# How should I time feeding and watering while running amateur canicross?

Tags: dogs, feeding, drinking

I live with my 3-year-old mix of labrador and golden in big city and we started jogging together. For now we run 5km or maximum 10km long routes, about two times per week. If it matters, temperatures now in my city will be about 0 °C (32 °F)

I would like to know what are best strategies for feeding and watering dog?

1. Is amount of fodder given on package for active dog just enough?
2. How many hours before or after such run the dog should get its food? (Note: for now she is eating twice a day, at 7 a.m. and 7 p.m.) I try to give it at least 2 hours break after feeding before run and, if feeding, after at least 40 minutes after run.
3. What about maintaining hydration while running? Should I take some water for 10km run to provide it in halfway?

Comment: Please choose one question to ask here, then ask your other questions as new questions. You will get more detailed answers to your questions that way. See [Why is it better to ask all my questions separately, and not all at once?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/q/1837/481)